# Selecting dataframe rows by muliple conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multipleselection

I could select rows from pandas df based on some conditions:

```
    cardio = df[df.indications == 'Cardiovascular / cardiology']
    end_aug = '2020-08-31'
    start_aug = '2020-08-01'

    mask = (df['date']>start_aug) & (df['date']<=end_aug)
    df = df.loc[mask,df['indications']]
```

but I wanted to use also "cardio" variable to narrow down my selection in ['indications'] column like:

```
    df = df.loc[mask,df['indications']== 'Neoplasms / cancer / oncology']
```

but the above code returned an error: IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

How can I use the mask and another selection, in my case by using the "cardio" variable?

Comment: `df.loc[mask&(df['indications']== 'Neoplasms / cancer / oncology')]`?

Comment: @henry thanks. It returns an empty dataframe and this: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison

Comment: @henry sorry it works! I forgot a parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```
searchfor = ['Neoplasms', 'cancer', 'oncology']
df = df[df['indications'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))]
```

Comment: thanks. Is searchfor list case sensitive for .contains?

Comment: Yes. better change all to lower case: df.str.lower()